# Help speeding up MySql Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How would I speed up this mysql query?

```
   SET @rank = 0;  

  UPDATE dbTable 
     SET rank_fd = @rank := @rank + 1 
ORDER BY fd2 DESC, fd3 DESC;
```

This query updates ~300,000 table rows. It just takes way too long.... Simple control panel (turbo panel?) says mysqld is only using 8-9% cpu. I know this is always gonna be true, but this query doesn't take nearly as long on my Core i7 machine. I think it takes about 5-10 minutes on my P4 dedicated server... that wouldn't be a problem except I have to do it more than once for different values. It also makes other mysql operations extremely slow (almost hanging), which affects website performances drastically.

Software:

- CentOS release 5.4 (Final),
- Simple Control Panel version 1.4.8,
- PHP 5.2.16
- MySQL client version: 5.1.52

Hardware:

- Intel Pentium 4 CPU 3.0GHz
- 2GB Ram

**MORE INFO (ADDED 3/6/2011 @ 10:06PM CST):**

```
//Core i7 920 @ 2.6GHz, 6GB Ram
UPDATE dbTable SET rank_fd =999999999;
#275037 row(s) affected. ( Query took 7.0708 sec )

SET @rank =0;
#Your SQL query has been executed successfully ( Query took 0.0003 sec )

UPDATE dbTable SET rank_fd = @rank := @rank +1 ORDER BY fd2 DESC, fd3 DESC ;
#275037 row(s) affected. ( Query took 9.9931 sec )



//P4 3.0GHz, 2GB Ram
UPDATE dbTable SET rank_fd =999999999;
#Affected rows: 291468 (Query took 8.2165 sec)

SET @rank =0;
#Your SQL query has been executed successfully (Query took 0.0002 sec)

UPDATE dbTable SET rank_fd = @rank := @rank +1 ORDER BY fd2 DESC, fd3 DESC ;
#Affected rows: 291469 (Query took 305.2104 sec)
```

**MORE INFO (ADDED 3/7/2011 @ 6:37PM CST):**

I've got some new info. If I do a select statement on the P4:

```
SET @rank =0;
SELECT @rank := @rank +1 AS rank_fd FROM dbTable ORDER BY fd2 DESC, fd3 DESC LIMIT 0, 300000;  
#Showing rows 0 - 29 (292,437 total, Query took 3.0448 sec)
```

It only takes 3 seconds to calculate everything. The no-calc batch update statement only takes 8 seconds. What is all the extra work being done that causes it fo go above 300 seconds with my original statement. Is there a way to catch update after the select calc statement that doesn't involve PHP. I only say this because if I loop this in PHP, it's gonna take much longer than the original statement.

Thanks for all the help so far!!!

Comment: This kind of query is slow. It could be faster to dump the whole table to external application, update it there, truncate it on db and insert it from external application to db.

What do You need rank_fd for?

Comment: @PiZzL3
: you have neglected important information: namely the Disk I/O subsystem....

Comment: Yeah, this kind of query is probably getting I/O bound.

Comment: I believe the hard drive is just a regular 7200rpm you can buy at any store, nothing special, no raid configuration. If I can run a benchmark in someway for you, please tell me how. I'm don't know much about server management.

Comment: @Michas: rank_fd is the rank (leaderboard place) determined by the ORDER BY clause. I cache this because it's too costly to update every time a players stats change.

Comment: @PiZzL3: Why don't You create rank_fd in PHP after the select? Could You show me Your select with rank_fd?

Comment: @Michas: There is no select in PHP or SQL. I use this statement because so far, it's the fastest way to do the job. It orders, ranks and writes the ranks to each row in a single statement (2 if you count the @var set) without any php. I used to use the php to select and count the ranks, then I would update them all in a php loop (which caused a HUGE performance bottleneck as mysql is way faster at this when not transferring the data between mediums).

Comment: The old select I used was this (which doesn't do any updating):  `SET @rank =0;
SELECT @rank := @rank +1 AS rank_fd FROM dbTable ORDER BY fd2 DESC, fd3 DESC LIMIT 0, 300000;`

Comment: You may be on to something there.... I just ran the select query on my P4 and it spit out all 300k results in 2 seconds. Even loaded them to the page in about 10 seconds.

Comment: Any ideas? I still haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

You're modifying every row in the table, of course it will be slow. Depending on how `rank_fd` is used, you may be able to get away with just putting indexes on `fd2` and `fd3` and calculating the rank at runtime.

Comment: table, not database.  But yes, 300+K records isn't trivial

Comment: Well I don't think that indexing fd2/3 will help. Ordering those hardly takes any time at all in a separate query (so I assume it wouldn't take long in this one either). Is there a different way to run that query to make it go faster (such as a different query(s))? It would also have to be done with minimal php as that tends to turn into a huge performance bottleneck in these types of calculations.

Comment: Calculating this at runtime doesn't seem like an option as it would have to be calculated across 30 other category types. And I'm unsure of how indexing all the table fields would affect performance. I think every time you update a field, the index would have to be updated too.

Comment: The point is that MySQL is able to update the index incrementally every time you perform an insert; whereas, you're trying to do bulk updates every once in a while. Indexes on columns helps MySQL do ordering, so you can make the order by query cheaper.

Comment: Is there anyway to prevent the hanging? 8-9% cpu and it's hanging is very frustrating.

Comment: Would indexing speed up the rank query at all? I can't get around doing that query.

Comment: MySQL does not support throttling queries. You'll have to figure out how to optimize or eliminate it.

Comment: The other problem with your query is that it's basically one big for loop; there is no way to parallelize the query because each relies on the result of the last query.

Comment: I've posted some benchmarks above. I'm gonna be looking at my tables to see what the difference is. I don't think the P4 should be that slow on the rank query since it's just as fast on the mass update query.

Comment: @PiZzL3, there is no computation going on in the mass update, so the processor will almost certainly not make a difference.  the difference is that you're asking your p4 to run 300k consecutive calculations.  its getting bogged down. you also didn't mention RAM in the other computer

Comment: How is the P4 getting bogged down at 8-9% cpu usage?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stored procedure and temp tables to speed up your ranking process.

The following example uses a player score table with 1.5 million rows with 500K player scores over 3 rounds (500K * 3) and updates the rankings for round 1 (500K rows) in approx. 5 seconds.

Hope this helps :)

**Example table and stored procedure**

```
drop table if exists player_scores;
create table player_scores
(
round_id smallint unsigned not null,
player_id int unsigned not null,
score_1 int unsigned not null default 0,
score_2 int unsigned not null default 0,
rank int unsigned not null default 0,
primary key (round_id, player_id)
)
engine=myisam;

drop procedure if exists update_player_score_ranking;

delimiter #
create procedure update_player_score_ranking
(
p_round_id smallint unsigned
)
begin

  create table tmp_player_scores engine=memory select 
    round_id, player_id, score_1, score_2, @rank:= @rank + 1 as rank
  from 
    player_scores 
  inner join (select @rank:=0) r
  where
   round_id = p_round_id
  order by 
    score_1 desc, score_2 desc;

  delete from player_scores where round_id = p_round_id;
  insert into player_scores select * from tmp_player_scores;

  drop table if exists tmp_player_scores;

end #

delimiter ;
```

**Test results:**

```
select count(*) from player_scores;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1500000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

select count(*) from player_scores where round_id = 1;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   500000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)

select * from player_scores where round_id = 1 order by score_1 desc, score_2 desc limit 5;
+----------+-----------+---------+---------+------+
| round_id | player_id | score_1 | score_2 | rank |
+----------+-----------+---------+---------+------+
|        1 |    456937 |   65534 |   49579 |    0 |
|        1 |     72439 |   65534 |   44537 |    0 |
|        1 |     16427 |   65534 |   43045 |    0 |
|        1 |    259871 |   65534 |   32095 |    0 |
|        1 |    324702 |   65534 |   15227 |    0 |
+----------+-----------+---------+---------+------+
5 rows in set (0.71 sec)


call update_player_score_ranking(1);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (5.57 sec)

select * from player_scores where round_id = 1 order by rank limit 5;
+----------+-----------+---------+---------+------+
| round_id | player_id | score_1 | score_2 | rank |
+----------+-----------+---------+---------+------+
|        1 |    456937 |   65534 |   49579 |    1 |
|        1 |     72439 |   65534 |   44537 |    2 |
|        1 |     16427 |   65534 |   43045 |    3 |
|        1 |    259871 |   65534 |   32095 |    4 |
|        1 |    324702 |   65534 |   15227 |    5 |
+----------+-----------+---------+---------+------+
5 rows in set (1.29 sec)
```

Comment: Wow that's a lot of stuff that I don't quite understand yet... I'm gonna look into it though. Thanks!